# Substring Matching within a paragraph using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `<p>Example string</p>` With some text inside. I want to use css to search for a word within that paragraph.

I know this is possible if you have e.g. `<a href="test"></a>` All you have to do then is:

```
a[href*="test"]{}
```

But when I try to do this with my paragraph I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried:

```
[p*="string"]{}

p[*="string"]{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**, this is not possible using CSS only, what you are using is `element[attr=val]` selector which only selects elements with that particular attribute with that specific values. You need to use jQuery or Javascript with a regex to track the pattern and apply styles to its elements.

On the other hand you can create custom attributes with a prefix of `data-` so for example you can do something like

```
<p data-custom="Holder Text">Want to change this</p>
<p data-custom="Holder Text">Want to change this</p>
<p data-custom="Holder Text 2">Dont Touch This</p>

p[data-custom="Holder Text"] {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6F29/)

But again, this won't make sense here, you can simply assign the classes if you are aware what elements need to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot this using CSS only, however you can check [this blog post](http://richard2001.blogspot.com/2010/02/select-elements-by-innerhtml-with.html) about how to achieve this using jQuery.

Basically you should use `:contains` selector:

```
$("p:contains('John')")
```

Comment: `if(p.innerHTML.match(/text/))` without jquery